# ASP.NET redirect a request

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a webservice x, when handles request to it, it will generate a request to another webservice y and use the response (might contain image or text) from y as the response to the original request. I have the following code to make the call, but how can I set the response?

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
{
    string uri2 = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}/{1}", Site2Root, context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);

    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri2);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Why not just create a webservice method that returns the same type as webservice `y`?

Comment: How would that help? You mean really doing 'redirect'? how to do thta?

Comment: This looks a lot like an HttpHandler. If you want to create a web service, then actually create one, then add a reference to the webservice in `y`. Call `y` from `x` and return its' response. But it does sound more like your looking for a proxy not a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to execute the webRequest by calling GetResponse.  Then you can call Response.BinaryWrite() or Response.Write with whatever content you returned from the first call. Here is an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/HTTPReverseProxy.aspx) project of this proxy code. It's not the best example but it should get you started.

Comment: But how could I get out the response from webservice y, assuming that the data could be binary data or text data.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to proxy the response and return whatever you get.  If you set the headers appropriately it should work fine.

Comment: sorry, what do u mean 'proxy the response'? is there a method to help doing that?